# In Xcode 4.2 How can i Use UITableView data to create and update a spreadsheet model view?

Tags: xcode4.2, ipad, ipad-2

I have an idea where I'd like to use tableviews to input data and then have it appear/update in a  "Spreadsheet looking" model view.

Adding cell rows within a tableview will add cells to the resulting spreadsheet type final view.

I understand tableviews but not sure how to get the result I am lokking for.

I'd love to know if I could somehow just use an existing excel doc and link the cells to tableview data.

Any info would be appreciated.

Thanks